# Is ‘In pace with’ correct?

Tags: phrase-usage

There is the phrase ‘to keep pace with’ in English, but I couldn’t find ‘in pace with’ in main sources online. Is it correct?

> **Example**:
>
> Technological developments in this country are not **in pace
> with** global innovations.

Comment: The idiomatically well-established usage is [*in **step** with*, not *in **pace** with*.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=are+in+step+with%2Care+in+pace+with&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Care%20in%20step%20with%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Care%20in%20pace%20with%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: ...but mainstream Anglophones do say *Technological developments in this country [**have not kept pace with**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=have+not+kept+pace+with&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chave%20not%20kept%20pace%20with%3B%2Cc0) global innovations.*

Answer (score 2):

Google Ngrams show a number of examples of *[is not in pace with,are not in pace with](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is%20not%20in%20pace%20with%2Care%20not%20in%20pace%20with&year_start=1990&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3)*

> Fundamentals of Medical Physiology-Ebook - Page 292 Harminder Singh, ‎Itika Singh · 2018 *This shows that plasma glucose is not in pace with absorption and excretion*,

> Detailed Project Profiles on Dairy & Dairy Products (2nd Edn.)
> NPCS board · 2012 *With various development in milk production methods availability of milk is increasing even though it is not in pace with rise in population.*

> New Horizons in Insect Science: Towards Sustainable Pest Akshay Kumar Chakravarthy · 2015 PAGE 390 *This is quite apparent from the fact that the production is not in pace with the increase in area.*

> Speaking to power: 27 voice tools : building bridges for ... - Page 127 Neela Mukherjee · 2009 *There is a hospital for beedi workers but there is no powerful treatment available . Elementary treatment is available and treatment is not in pace with the incidence of sickness*

However, the overwhelming majority of all examples are written by speakers of Indian English.

From this we can say that although common in Indian English, it is not a common collocation in British and American English.

Comment: It looks like a particular case.

Comment: So what to say instead?

Comment: @Sasan the two comments on your original question suggest the most common alternatives.